# Why does php password_hash() generate different hashes for the same input?

Tags: hash, php

I've been using `password_hash('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` for an internal system, and while I was testing the code, I saw that it generated different hashes for the same input.

Why does this happens, and how do `password_verify()` identify another hash as the same password if the hashes are different?

Is there an explanation about it's 'safeness'?

Comment: It's likely a duplicate, but the short answer is. Because `password_hash()` automatically generates a salt.

Comment: @MechMK1 definitely it is the question I had. I searched but didn't find this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like the documentation of `password_hash` states, a unique salt is being calculated for each time it is called.

> It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.

(source: [php manual - password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php))

Additionally the used options of the hashing process are stored in the generated hash itself(salt,cost,algo) so the `password_verify` has all information's it needs to verify if a plaintext matches a hash without being able to decrypt it.

> Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it.

(source: [enter link description here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php))

This also explains why the start of **most** hashes are identical. 
For example depending on the cost and algo used your hashes might always start with something like `$2y$10$` and from then on differ. *This behavior can however change between different frameworks, algorithms or other factors, so take this only as a example of how the cost and algo can be saved in the resulted hash.*

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) on php.net you can see that this function generates a secure salt every time you use it. So if you are using the same input there will be a different output because of this random salt.

In the [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php) section of your code the new salt will be used. The hash will be identical and a user is able to login.

If you want that your hash stays always the same you need to deliver an own salt with the option `salt` to `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`. This is not considered as secure if you are not knowing what you are doing. So i would prefer the automatically generated salt.

Comment: Not only do you need to know what you are doing for a manual salt, it is deprecated since PHP 7.0.0 and might be removed some time in the future, making it not the best option.